# How is fetching the secure token from AWS each time more secure?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Instead of using the access key + access key password, AWS has you use a token that expires every 12 hours.  To do this, you have to first use the access key + access key password to fetch this token.  After this, you can interact with their APIs.  If anyone gets access to the access key+password, you are obviously screwed.  If anyone gets access to the token, they have 12 hours to do damage.

I am not sure how this is really more secure though than just putting the key+password in a header of SSL when accessing amazon APIs.  I still need to put this key+password in CI systems for CD (locked to only pushing images to ECR of course so it is decently scoped to only that).

I don't see the purpose of fetching the token and would love to hear an explanation on how that is more secure as it sure is way way more of a hassle figuring all this out for CI.

Comment: This question seems to be better suited for [security.se].

Answer (score 1):

It's faster than authenticating every connection, and the infrastructure you are connecting to doesn't have to perform authentication, it only needs to confirm the token is valid.  Also if authentication is performed every connection, it needs to be fast. We don't want that. Authentication schemes that take a bit longer are more of a deterrent to attackers.

Comment: another reason it is secure is that the end user can split up getting a token from the applications using the token, so that the CI system doesn't need to know the access key at all.  it is quite common in enterprise/cloud environments to use a credential management system like vault.  of course, it is a bit like turtles all the way down, but that is a different story.

Comment: @toppk: absolutely, there are many advantages. Most API's have or will go this way too, or at least that's been my experience from converting some of these. And Vault is probably the defacto key management in AWS, and fairly easy to use/implement.

Answer (score 0):

A permanent access key id and secret are associated with an IAM user, and grant the bearer the permissions that user enjoys.  All of the permissions.

There are use cases where temporary credentials are granted to give the same access (to an IAM user) for a period of time.  As you point out, this reduces the time the credential is usable (which is a good thing) but doesn't otherwise reduce the level of access.  However, this isn't the only use case.

When temporary credentials are used to assume an IAM role, then only the permissions in the role granted by the credentials.  It's very common for such roles to be more limited than an IAM user's general access permissions.  For example, gaining access only to an RDS database.  This does reduce the level of access, and together with the limited time period, represents better protections if the credential leaks out.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how this is really more secure though than just putting the key+password in a header of SSL when accessing amazon APIs.

An example scenario: You inadvertently log requests. [This is not theoretical](https://abcnews.go.com/Technology/facebook-admits-inadvertently-storing-hundreds-millions-user-passwords/story?id=61839766). Logged keys and passwords would be valid months/years later unless revoked; logged tokens become rapidly useless.

> I still need to put this key+password in CI systems for CD (locked to only pushing images to ECR of course so it is decently scoped to only that).

Not if you use AWS CodeBuild, which can use an IAM profile.